# Can you pass argument to mixin in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using NuxtJS's head tag.  The meta tags in my application are often repeated or only have a slight variation.

I would like to pass the title into the mixin and then reuse the code for all pages in the application.  However, I am not sure how to do this in vuejs.  any suggestions?

```
export const metatags = {
  head () {
    const organization = this.$store.state.loadedData

    const title = 'Classes & Lessons - ' + organization.organization.name + ' ' +
      organization.target_locations[0]

    const description =
      (organization.organization.name
        ? organization.organization.name
        : '') +
      ' is ' +
      (organization.services.length > 0
        ? organization.target_locations[0]
        : '') +
      "'s premier " +
      (organization.services.length > 0
        ? organization.services[0].name
        : '') +
      ' and ' +
      (organization.services.length > 1
        ? organization.services[1].name
        : '') +
      ' training centers'

    const logo = process.env.AMAZONAWS_IMAGE_URL +
      organization.organization.primary_logo_id + '_350.' + organization.organization.logo_extension

    const favicon = logo

    const domain = 'https://' + this.$store.state.domain

    return {
      title,
      meta: [
        {
          name: 'description',
          content: description
        },
        {
          property: 'og:title',
          content: title
        },
        {
          property: 'og:site_name',
          content: organization.organization.name
        },
        {
          property: 'og:description',
          content: description
        },
        {
          property: 'og:image',
          content: logo
        },
        {
          property: 'og:url',
          content: domain
        },
        {
          name: 'twitter:title',
          content: title
        },
        {
          name: 'twitter:description',
          content: description
        },
        {
          name: 'twitter:image',
          content: logo
        }
      ],
      link: [
        { rel: 'canonical', href: domain },
        { rel: 'icon', href: logo },
        { rel: 'shortcut icon', href: logo },
        { rel: 'apple-touch-icon', href: logo },
        { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: favicon }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sure, `mixin` will take the context of the component where is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to pass any argument into your `head()` method directly, but `this` is [available there](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-head). It doesn't matter whether the `head()` is defined on the page directly or using a mixin. Just make sure to not override it on individual pages....